# como tratar uma variável 'undefined'

Tags: funções, undefined

Estou recebendo valores de um elemento html (input) e tratando este resultado com uma função, porem quando a variável é 'undefined' o código não e executado. Eu preciso que quando o usuário não digite nada no input retorne a mensagem da condição 'valor === undefined' ao invés de 'NaN'.

```js
        function resultado() {
            var valor = document.getElementById('entrada').value;
            var valor = parseFloat(valor);

            if (valor !== undefined){
                document.getElementById('ceil').innerHTML = Math.ceil(valor);
                document.getElementById('floor').innerHTML = Math.floor(valor);
                document.getElementById('round').innerHTML = Math.round(valor);
            }
            if (valor === undefined){
                document.getElementById('ceil').innerHTML = 'digite um valor valido';
                document.getElementById('floor').innerHTML = 'digite um valor valido';
                document.getElementById('round').innerHTML = 'digite um valor valido';
            }
            if (valor == 0){
                document.getElementById('ceil').innerHTML = '0,00';
                document.getElementById('floor').innerHTML = '0,00';
                document.getElementById('round').innerHTML = '0,00';
            }
        }
```

```html
    <form>
        <input type="number" name="" placeholder="digite um valor" id="entrada">
        <button type="button" onclick="resultado()">Resultado</button>
    </form>

    <div>
        <p id="ceil">Saida resultado math.ceil()</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p id="floor">Saida resultado math.floor()</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p id="round">Saida resultado math.round()</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Não duplique perguntas, portanto os comentários foram desativado aqui para que continue na [pergunta original](/q/588990/3635). Siga as orientações feitas na pergunta original para melhorar a pergunta, leia os links para entender o objetivo do site.